# Is it possible to set default TTL for each keys and keys with prefix in reactive redis?

Tags: java, redis

I am asking if it is possible to pre set default TTL for each cache keys when using ReactiveRedisTemplate because I can't seem to find references matching my expectation.

Like when using RedisCacheManager we can define Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> which we can assign to cacheDefaults

Is it possible to set default ttl like that when using ReactiveRedisTemplate?

I tried looking into the implementations of ReactiveRedisTemplate but I cannot seem to find anything that matches default settings for cache keys default TTL.

I tried exploring other guides but I still cannot find suitable answers.

I wanted to be able to set default cache keys in ReactiveRedisTemplate such as
key1: 100 seconds
key2: 200 seconds

So when ReactiveRedisTemplate is setting the cache for said key it will follow the ttl defined in defaults

Answer (score 0):

You want to have different TTL values for different keys - it can't be considered as defaults. There is a method `expire()` of ReactiveRedisTemplate for setting TTL for the key:

```
public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<Boolean> expire(K key, Duration timeout)
```

See Javadoc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisTemplate.html#expire(K,java.time.Duration)